# Why should this question stay open?

Tags: discussion, scope

**[Should biblical laws apply to non-Christians?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1148/6071)**

This question points out two opposing Christian views and asks which is correct. It's either opinion based or a truth question. I flagged it but my flag was rejected. Why is it appropriate given the current site standards?

It's also very similar to [How should Christians participate in a democracy?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3322/6071) which was closed.

Comment: Interesting question. What is the point of following biblical laws when you don't believe in them?

Comment: For the record, something is wacky here. According to the event log I am the one that "declined" your flag, but I plead innocent! What I _did_ do is see the question go through the close vote review queue and voted to "leave open" (reasoning that it is a question from '11 that hasn't hit the home page or otherwise been disruptive and didn't need special attention). Apparently that action declined your flag which I would not otherwise have done. At most I would have marked it as helpful but not taken action. Knowing that there was a flag rather that just a VTC I might have done a closer review.

Comment: Very weird! I guess it doesn't matter if it does stay inactive.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Jon Ericson locked it again 6 hours ago, but this time for good.

Comment: @Caleb: It happens because the flag was "recommend closure" if sufficient "do not close" votes are registered with no close votes, the flag is declined automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why your flag was declined; perhaps he can offer an explanation. That said, I just locked it as having historical significance. That question dates from the earliest days of this site, and would (or rather, should) definitely not fly today. So, now it is effectively closed.

Comment: And it's open again. I definitely don't want to get involved with any mod disagreement and if the mods do want it to stay open that's fine, I just think it needs a lot of fixing if so (which will probably invalidate the current answers.)

Comment: It was unlocked by Community♦, so I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: @El'endia Starman: Is it possible you didn't change the time for the lock? The default is to lock the post for one hour. (Arguably, it should be permanent for the "historical lock" reason.)

Comment: @JonEricson: [facepalm] That's precisely why. I'm used to using locks permanently. Also, maybe the default for the historical reason could be permanent?

Comment: I made a [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234120/1438). Not an urgent problem, however. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson: Excellent. Thanks! :)